# Searching two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE files_list
(
    'listid' INT, 
    'name' VARCHAR(25), 
    'synonym' VARCHAR(25), 
    'description' VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE files_tags
(
    'tag_name' VARCHAR(25), 
    'listid' INT
);
```

If someone uses the keyword "dragon ball", at the moment, I use following query to search my_list for possible matches:

```
SELECT * 
FROM files_list
WHERE name LIKE '%dragon%' 
OR synonym LIKE '%dragon%' 
OR description LIKE '%dragon%' 
OR name LIKE '%ball%' 
OR synonym LIKE '%ball%' 
OR description LIKE '%ball%'
```

I am not sure how to search both tables using one query. I want to show the user following data in the search result: name, synonym, description and all tags.

**My Questions**
1. Is there any way to make the current mysql query shorter?
2. How can I combine it with `files_tags` table, 
- to show rows from `files_list` which has a match in `files_tags`, but not in `files_list`?
- to show rows from `files_list` which has a match in `files_list, but may not in`files_tags`?

You can see the current displayed result at http://hsbsitez.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394041/mysql-how-to-search-multiple-tables-for-a-string-existing-in-any-column See this question your answer is there :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to search multiple tables for a string existing in any column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394041/mysql-how-to-search-multiple-tables-for-a-string-existing-in-any-column)

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to join the tables.

```
SELECT name, synonym, description, tag_name FROM `files_list` WHERE ( name LIKE '%dragon%' OR synonym LIKE '%dragon%' OR description LIKE '%dragon%' OR name LIKE '%ball%' OR synonym LIKE '%ball%' OR description LIKE '%ball%' )
OUTER JOIN files_tags on files_tags.listid = files_list.listid
```

`OUTER JOIN` will make sure all tags are selected, this will create duplicate rows when multiple tags per id are available, with the only difference being the tag

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using union to actually get the columns you want for each unioned query.  And this case, a subquery seems to make more sense:

```
SELECT name, synonym, description FROM files_list WHERE
       name LIKE '%dragon%' OR synonym LIKE '%dragon%' OR description LIKE '%dragon%'
       OR name LIKE '%ball%' OR synonym LIKE '%ball%' OR description LIKE '%ball%'
       OR listid IN (SELECT listid FROM files_tags WHERE tag_name='dragon' OR tag_name='ball');
```

Some additional questions:
When you say you want show the user "all tags", do you mean all tags that exist for a given listid?  Or just those that matched?  And if description like "%dragon%", is dragon one of the tags you want returned even if it isn't in file_tags?