# mySQL: How to search in multiple tables in database?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search

I want to search in two tables. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394041/mysql-how-to-search-multiple-tables-for-a-string-existing-in-any-column) but didn't worked. I'm getting error "Unkown Column...."

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post"
 <input type="text" name="search_keyword">
 <input type="submit" name="button_search"> 
</form>
```

**MYSQL SELECT AND PHP:**

```
    if(isset($_POST['button_search']))
    {
      $search_keyword = $_POST['search_keyword'];

      $select = mysql_query("SELECT * from table_1 WHERE match(name_1) against ($search_keyword) 
        union all SELECT * from table_2 WHERE match(name_2) against ($search_keyword)");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
      {
        echo $row['question'];
        echo $row['category_name'];
      }
   }
```

**TABLES:**

*For example:*

**Table 1:**

table name: table_1

Values (table 1):

```
+-------+-------------+
| id_1  |   name_1    |
+-------+-------------+ 
|  1     | Phinoy     | 
|  2     | Go         | 
+-------+-------------+
```

**Table 2:**

table name: table_2

Values:

```
+-------+-------------+
| id_2  |   name_2    |
+-------+-------------+ 
|  1     |   Gi       | 
|  2     | Phinas     | 
+-------+-------------+
```

If I search "P" or "Ph" , it will show the values "Phinoy and Phinas".

Comment: you want to display "Phinoy and Phinas" as search result OR auto suggestion while type in the box

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394041/mysql-how-to-search-multiple-tables-for-a-string-existing-in-any-column) which is answered below

Comment: @roullie thanks but i'm confused with match() and against()

Comment: Why do you have two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Well. First you need is use an INNER JOIN for comparing two tables at the same time. In this code, we are concatening the result of the table 1 and the table 2, then we are calling the table_1 and with a INNER JOIN we will compare the table_2 if in the table_1 there are any result LIKE table_2 and only just happening in the column name_1 and name_2.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT 
    CONCAT(table_1.name_1,' and ',table_2.name_2) 
    FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 
    ON table_1.name_1 LIKE table_2.name_2";
    mysql_query($query);
?>
```